# select every year SQL BY country

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, group-by, sql-update

I have 3 tables like below:

Table client: a list of clients with their first and last names, full address.0

Table Produit: a list of articles sent on the web site containing the name of the article, the country where it was manufactured, and its price.

Table Actions: a list of all transactions done by clients with the time of the transactions.

```
  CREATE TABLE Client(Id_client integer PRIMARY KEY, First_Name varchar, Last_Name varchar);
  CREATE TABLE Produit (id_produit varchar PRIMARY KEY, Country varchar, Article_Name varchar, Price varchar);
  CREATE TABLE Transactions (Id_client varchar, id_produit varchar, date_t varchar);
```

**Output desired**

get the average price of the first article bought by all users in japan for every year.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, what you have tried, and explain why it does not work.

Comment: @MudassirHasan what do you mean  didn't understand

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are very vendor specific. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses window functions in a inner query to rank the transactions of each client and each year; then, the outer query filters on the earlier transaction in each group, and uses aggregation to compute the average of the product.

Assumptions:

- your RDBMS supports window functions
- `date_t` is a date-like datatype
- your RDBMS supports the `YEAR()` function

Query:

```
SELECT 
    year_date,
    AVG(price) avg_price
FROM (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(date_t) year_date,
        p.price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(t.date_t), t.id_client ORDER BY p.date_t) rn
    FROM Transactions t
    INNER JOIN Produit p ON t.id_produit = p.id_produit 
    WHERE p.country = 'Japan'
) x
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY year_date
```

Comment: $sqlite3 database.sdb < main.sql
Error: near line 26: near "(": syntax error

Comment: @Miss: which version of sqlite? Did you check if it conforms to the assumptions listed in my answer?

Comment: @Miss you need sqlite 3.25 or newer.